# How to pass path to an Hive external table from shell script?

Tags: sql, shell, scripting, hive

I am creating an Hive external table via a `hiveq.sql` script:

```
Create external table if not exists abc
(
id string
)
Row format delimited
fields terminated by '|'
Stored as textfile
LOCATION '${hiveconf:loc}/xyz/data';
```

But i am getting below exception when i am trying to execute it with Shell Script:

```
hive -hiveconf test_loc=/om/name/loc -f hiveq.sql
```

Exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: 
  Relative path in absolute URI: ${hiveconf:test_loc%7D/xyz/data
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Typo... :-)

`loc` Vs. `test_loc`

---

```
${hiveconf:loc}
```

---

```
-hiveconf test_loc
```